# Pythagorean like theorem for general spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, soft-question

There are laws, for example Pythagorean theorem, for calculating distance of two points, say $d(a,b)$, using third point and knowing $d(a,c)$ and $d(c,b)$ in vector spaces. My question is that for wich spaces we can do something like?

Edit 1:
There are many metric spaces that don't accept some theorems like Pythagorean because we don't have any think like right triangle at all. In my view we need some think like paralled lines and right angel maybe a inner product or else!

Edit 2:
Pythagorean like: A releation between $d(a,b)$, $d(a,c)$ and $d(c,b)$.
For example: In general for any metric space we have: $d(a,b) \leq d(a,c) + d(c,b)$

Comment: I would ask people to think twice before voting to close this question because it is deeper than it may seem at first glance. I for one would like to see an answer so if it is closed I'll just ask it myself.

Comment: There is a spherical geometry analogue of the Pythagorean theorem so my hunch is that the space would have to be homogeneous with a constant curvature.

Comment: It's really unclear (to me, at least) what is the question here.  What is "something like"?

Comment: In the case of normed vector spaces, perhaps the correct Pythagorean-like condition is the parallelogram law, together with the fact that it holds for a norm if and only if that norm is induced by some inner product.

Comment: I agree with @RobertIsrael, the question is very unclear.

Comment: I think that one generalization is the notion of Riemannian manifolds; then you have triangles, distances and angles, parralel transport of vectors, etc, and I think that the sectional curvature can be interpreted as measuring the deviation from the pytagorean theorem for infinitesimally small triangles.

Comment: @PeterFranek, one important feature of the pythagorean theorem is that only knowing the lengths of two sides of a right triangle allows us compute the length of the third side *without knowing the location or orientation of the triangle*. I think this is not true for all Reimannian manifolds since the curvature can vary from point to point. This is part of what intrigues me about the question personally.